# Why does Geoserver not serve my primary key/ id?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver

I have a postgres/postgis table with the columns:

- gid [PK] serial NOT NULL,
- geom geometry(MultiPolygon,900913),
- crop text

My layer in Geoserver however only shows me the feature types "geom" and "crop", the "gid" is not listed.
Problem is, I need the gid to update data of a particular (the selected) polygon.

Is there a way to get the gid? If not, how do you bypass this problem?

Comment: look on the layer page and check the expose primary key box

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must to check "expose primary key" in your datastore [configuration](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/data-stores.html)
[image: DataStore configuration]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the stores on the GeoServer webpage left bar
2. Select your store from the list
3. On the middle position you will find an option **expose primary key**
4. Check it.
   Now you will find the pk and can run any operation with it

[image]