# How to SortBy a GetFeature WFS request by FeatureId (fid) in XML?

Tags: geoserver, xml, ogc, getfeature, sorting

This is my XML for a GetFeature request. I want to Sort By FeatureId (fid) but this doesn't work. I can't find an example of how to format this XML correctly:

(SEE THE ogc:SortBy SECTION)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:myws="http://mysrvr.com/solution/myws" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.1.0" service="WFS" maxFeatures="100" outputFormat="JSON">
   <Query typeName="myws:mylayer">
      <ogc:SortBy>
         <ogc:FeatureId>fid</ogc:FeatureId>
         <ogc:SortOrder>ASC</ogc:SortOrder>
      </ogc:SortBy>
   </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not supposed to work. SortBy is defined in the WFS 1.1.0 standard as

> The SORTBY parameter is used to specify a list of property names whose
>   values should be used to order (upon presentation) the set of feature
>   instances that satify the query. The value of the SORTBY parameter
>   shall have the form “PropertyName [A|D][,PropertyName [A|D],…]” where
>   the letter A is used to indicate an ascending sort and the letter D is
>   used to indicate a descending sort.

But featureID is not a property and therefore you can't use it with SORTBY. However, with GeoServer you have a workaround and you can publish the primary key which is used for generating featureID also as a normal property. See [Why does Geoserver not serve my primary key/ id?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43973/why-does-geoserver-not-serve-my-primary-key-id)